# How to interchange an element within multidimensional list in python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm unable to change the elements of a multidimensional list. The code does work on a simple list, but not on a lists within a list. I assume there is a correct way of modifying a multidimensional list?

The code I'm stuck with:

```
curpos = [[88, 118, 1], [200, 118, 0], [312, 118, 2],
   [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 4], [312, 230, 5],
   [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]]
movls = ['right', 'down', 'left']

def move_tile(current_loc, movlist):
    result = []
    temp = current_loc.copy()
    for i in temp:
        if i[2] == 0:
            empty = temp.index(i)
    for j in movlist:
        if j == 'right':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty+1][2] # the problem is here, it changes the origin current_loc instead of the copy temp
            temp[empty+1][2] = 0 
        elif j == 'down':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty+3][2]
            temp[empty+3][2] = 0
        elif j == 'left':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty-1][2]
            temp[empty-1][2] = 0
        elif j == 'up':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty-3][2]
            temp[empty-3][2] = 0
        print(temp) # this outputs [[88, 118, 1], [200, 118, 2], [312, 118, 0], [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 4], [312, 230, 5], [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]]
        result.append(temp) # but this appends [88, 118, 0], [200, 118, 1], [312, 118, 0], [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 0], [312, 230, 5], [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]
        temp = current_loc.copy() # does not reset the temporary var

    return result


print(move_tile(curpos, movls))
```

The correct output (without the `print(temp)` should be something like this:

```
[[[88, 118, 1], [200, 118, 2], [312, 118, 0],
  [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 4], [312, 230, 5],
  [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]],

   [[88, 118, 1], [200, 118, 4], [312, 118, 2],
    [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 0], [312, 230, 5],
    [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]],

    [[88, 118, 0], [200, 118, 1], [312, 118, 2],
     [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 4], [312, 230, 5],
     [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to ensure that `temp` is a separate list.  Making this change will generate the output that you have described above.

```
from copy import deepcopy

curpos = [[88, 118, 1], [200, 118, 0], [312, 118, 2],
   [88, 230, 3], [200, 230, 4], [312, 230, 5],
   [88, 342, 6], [200, 342, 7], [312, 342, 8]]
movls = ['right', 'down', 'left']

def move_tile(current_loc, movlist):
    result = []
    temp = deepcopy(current_loc)
    for i in temp:
        if i[2] == 0:
            empty = temp.index(i)
    for j in movlist:
        if j == 'right':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty+1][2] 
            temp[empty+1][2] = 0 
        elif j == 'down':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty+3][2]
            temp[empty+3][2] = 0
        elif j == 'left':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty-1][2]
            temp[empty-1][2] = 0
        elif j == 'up':
            temp[empty][2] = temp[empty-3][2]
            temp[empty-3][2] = 0
        result.append(temp) 
        temp = deepcopy(current_loc) 

    return result


print(move_tile(curpos, movls))
```